# why doesn't exist activate file in bin folder

Tags: python, conda, python-venv

I made venv using conda. it's my first time

```
conda create -n filename python=3.7
```

but there is not activate file in bin folder(in vscode interpreter, venv exists)

help me..!!

in zsh
[image]

in Python
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you created the environment with `conda` named `filename`, you need conda to activate it:

```bash
conda activate filename

# to deactivate
conda deactivate
```

If you run

```bash
conda env list
```

You would see the path to your environments. e.g.

```bash
# output
base * C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3
envmnt C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\filename
```

If you really want to directly use `source activate` You can find those scripts there.

Note: the `*` in front of environment name indicates which environment is currently active.

Comment: oh, thank you. Then, How could I make venv using conda command to use this command "source bin/activate"

Comment: You don't need that command. `conda activate filename` is all you need